# Haskell Efficient Program

Tags: haskell

I have this code:

```
trimorficos :: [Integer]
trimorficos = filter (trim) [0..]

trim :: Integer -> Bool
trim x = (show x) `isSuffixOf` (show (x^3))
      where a = show x
            b = show (x^3)

densityTrimorficos :: Integer -> Double
densityTrimorficos n = fromInteger (n - (genericLength (filter (<=10) trimorficos))) / fromInteger n
```

Why the last function  `densityTrimorficos` doesn't work?

Comment: I think you're going to need to give more context about what you're asking about. What doesn't work?

Comment: It works, but if I put `densityTrimorficos 10` doesn't do anything. But if you compile, it doesn't recognize a error

Comment: @mathandtic: well there is no error in a slow function. But what Carcigenicate means is that you should explain what the function is supposed to do. What problem does it aim to solve?

Comment: Related: [*infinite lists, lazy evaluation and length*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35958831/2751851)

Comment: Shouldn't `filter` be replaced with `takeWhile`, since `trimorficos` only increases.

Comment: the density of trimorphs up to n, in other words, trimorphs up to n `div` n

Answer (score 1):

`trimorficos` is an infinite list.

`filter (<=10) trimorficos` will never produce the end-of-list `[]` at the very end. To do so, it should verify that, from a certain point onward, `trimorficos` contains only numbers >10, but that would require infinite time.
Basically, `filter` will returns something like `a:b:c:nonTerminating` instead of `a:b:c:[] = [a,b,c]`.

Consequently, `genericLength` fails to terminate, since it tries to evaluate `nonTerminating` into either `d:...` or `[]` but that requires infinite time.

As pointed out above in the comments, you probably want `takeWhile (<=10) trimorficos` instead, which will produce `[]` as soon as the first >10 number is encountered. Note that this will not check the rest of the list, unlike `filter`.