# removing duplicates from a list in haskell

Tags: list, haskell, duplicates

I am trying to delete consecutive duplicates in a list; for instance, given the list `[1,2,2,3,4]`, it the function I need must return `[1,3,4]`.

My code at the end of the question, however, doesn't work if trailing duplicates are in list, like in `[1,2,3,4,4]`.

I also want to do it in as simple terms as possible, how can I do this?

```
myCom :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]
myCom (x:y:ys@(z:_))
    | x == y    =  myCom ys
    | otherwise = x  : myCom (y:ys)
myCom ys = ys
```

Comment: Do you mean all duplicates, or just consecutive ones?

Comment: `nub` https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:nub

Comment: `nub` is O(n^2) unfortunately - the best way I believe is to use the `fromList` and `toList` functions from `Data.Set` and then just use `toList . fromList`.

Comment: @tex No, `nub [1,2,2,3,4]` is `[1,2,3,4]`, but the OP wants `[1,3,4]`.

Comment: Good call. I misinterpreted the requirements.

Comment: `[x | x <- group [1,2,2,3,4], [_] <- [x], x <- x]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first pattern match you have only catches lists with at least 3 elements.
That is why when the duplicates are at the end of the list when

```
myCom [4,4]
```

is called it simply uses

```
myCom ys = ys
```

and returns itself. You can catch this by defining myCom for lists with at least 2 elements as below (you werent't using z anyway):

```
myCom (x:y:ys)
  | x == y    =  myCom ys
  | otherwise = x  : myCom (y:ys)
myCom ys = ys
```

This gives

myCom [1,2,2,3,4,4] = [1,3]

There is still an issue with 3 (an odd number) consecutive numbers. For example we get:

```
myCom [1,2,2,2] = [1,2]
```

but I understand that this is desired behavior.

Comment: I think this is the right answer, you just need to adjust the first pattern matching.

Comment: if `myCom [1,2,2,2] = [1,2]` is desired behavior, then what should `myCom [1,2,2,2,2]` be? is it `[1]` again, or `[1,2,2]`?

Answer (score 2):

I would use `Maybe` to represent a length of one as a success condition. This works well with Haskell's pattern-matching syntax. You can then use `group` (from Data.List) and filter out the `Nothing`s using `catMaybe` (from Data.Maybe) :

```
myCom = catMaybes . map lenOne . group
  where lenOne [x] = Just x
        lenOne _   = Nothing
```

Answer (score 1):

From a comment I see that the function `Data.Set.nub` just does what the OP asks.

However, my first attempt to solve the problem was the following, which only removes duplicates if they are consecutive (e.g. `[1,2,1,2,1,2]` is not changed):

```
concat $ filter (\x -> length x == 1) $ Data.List.group [1,2,3,4,4]
```

I hope this answer could be useful to some random user ending up on this page.

Comment: Although this is simple to read, it is potentially inefficient, since `length` [traverses the whole list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35958999/7096763), just to check that there is no second element.